# how to disable gnome lock screen curtain in ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: gnome, lock-screen, 17.10

I have disabled the screen lock which requires a password (settings->privacy) and I have activated the screen blanking which switches off the display (settings->power->blank_screen).
But when I want to activate the dark display and touch a key, the display is switched on but there is the picture from the lock screen which I have to remove by hitting escape key. A password is not required. How can I get rid of this lock picture? (It is the same that is used for the screen lock).

Comment: To ask for clarity, you mean how to disable the lock-screen curtain? I would be interested in a solution for this as well.

Comment: I found this: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/672/disable-screen-shield/

Comment: Does it work on 17.10 with gnome 3.26?

Comment: yes works on 17.10 with gnome 3.26. don't use the Super+L key, you have to reboot.

Comment: O.k. since I'm used to log in when I'm booting up this might be not well suited for my case then, and looking at the extensions github it has sitting idle since June.

Comment: the link to the extension from @jms here , works. 
i clicked on github link though, there i copy paste the git clone command it had in instructions (it downloads the extension directly in the correct folder) , i did in terminal <$killall -3 gnome-shell> to restart gnome shell, i opened the tweak tool and enabled the extension.

Comment: if you have the chrome-gnome-shell extension installed (GNOME Shell integration), you can go to https://extensions.gnome.org/ with your chrome browser and install the gnome extensions directly from the browser screen.

Comment: The "don't hit Super-L" bit kills it for me, I use that all the time. Is there really no other way to get rid of this thing? Would replacing the display manager work?

Comment: For me the extension didn't work :(

Comment: This bug was reported 5 years ago and there is still no fix  from Canonical. It not only appears in gnome. There is no fix available today and this is a total shame for the linux community.

Comment: have you tried to toggle the setting `org.gnome.desktop.lockdown.disable-lock-screen` in `dconf-editor`?

Comment: org.gnome.desktop.lockdown.disable-lock-screen does not help

Answer (score -1):

I have a workaround for this.

1. Uninstall or disable light-locker in autostart.
2. Install xscreensaver
3. On the XScreensaver settings screen unselect screen locking.
4. On the advanced tab tick power management enable and set 0 for standby after and check Quick power off in blank only mode.

Comment: Are you sure this solves the issue? OP wants to disable the screen-shield (this one: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejs4C.png), which is a default feature in GNOME 3. These steps seem to have to effect on it.