# How to remove "phone style" Gnome swipe to unlock

Tags: gnome, 17.10

I need to remove the annoying new "locking" screen that shows a giant clock: I can't remove it with just moving the mouse (as with any other desktop environment), the animation is slow, and it isn't asking me for a password!

I managed to disable it, just to discover that now I can't lock my screen on purpose, so I can't go away from the computer.

Just to clarify, I want to:

- After some time the screen could go black, but if I move the mouse or press any key then I can use it directly (like a normal screensaver).
- If I press super-L then it is locked, and I must type the password to unlock (like a normal lock screen).

I found several "solutions", but none seems to work:

- https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/36256/how-do-i-disable-the-gnome-lock-screen/
- https://superuser.com/questions/793039/my-pc-is-not-a-phone-how-do-i-remove-the-swipey-pre-log-in-screen-from-gnome-3
- https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/672/disable-screen-shield/

Comment: You need to file a bug report against the extension - https://github.com/lgpasquale/gnome-shell-extension-disable-screenshield/issues

Comment: Just a pointer. you can start typing your password without clicking and dragging the screen shield first.

Comment: @Panther Looking at the extensions github it has sitting idle since June, and on the extensions page and in the issues people are complaining that it does not work anymore without anything happened. I do not think that this extension is a real solution right now.

Comment: @Videonauth but what alternate do you have ? 1. write your own extension or 2. file a feature request with gnome or ubuntu.

Comment: Not much except what you just said sadly. but introducing an extension as a solution which forces you to hard reset your machine because you accidentally pressed super+l for locking is not helping here sadly it just introduces other trouble, so I'd say in some user cases it may work as intended but in others it don't.

Comment: B.t.w. this is a possible duplicate of: https://askubuntu.com/q/966725/522934 or vice versa, I'm not flagging it yet because none of both has a suitable answer yet.

Comment: @pomsky: there isn't any password to write. Also, if this was a screen saver (as it should be) then my password keystrokes could go to any app... not a good idea from a security point of view.

Comment: I moved to KDE to get around this.

Comment: I moved too to KDE, but then my sound at headset stopped working :@ . I'm not caring a lot, as my PC is suggesting me to buy a new one anyway...

Comment: Even on fast computers, this [bug](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-control-center/issues/757), is so annoying.

Answer (score 12):

Open Ubuntu Software and install the GNOME Shell Extension called:

**Disable Screen Shield**

This works for Ubuntu 18.04

Source:
[Disable Screen Shield](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/672/disable-screen-shield/)
[image: Disable Screen Shield]

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Comment: This solution no longer works. The extension fails on recent versions of gnome.

Comment: @CoreyOConnor Same here, solution does not work anymore

Comment: Sometimes works, sometimes not on Ubuntu 18.04+

Comment: Per https://github.com/lgpasquale/gnome-shell-extension-disable-screenshield/issues/14 it does not work in 18.04

Answer (score 11):

Actual solution depends on exact requirements, but these may provide work-arounds (specifically, talking about the [gnome 3 screen curtain, illustrated here](https://superuser.com/questions/793039/my-pc-is-not-a-phone-how-do-i-remove-the-swipey-pre-log-in-screen-from-gnome-3) ):

- if you desire to have a normal basic screen lock enabled, yet don't want the "swipe-up screen curtain", then you may actually **just type your password on the curtain screen** without clicking/scrolling/mousing/etc, and it will work to unlock the screen.  *(Note: this assumes that only one account is configured to appear on the login greeter screen.)*
- it seems the screen curtain itself can't be disabled (a couple gnome-shell extensions have mixed reports of either no longer working (ubuntu 17+), or not working consistently), so it appears we're stuck with it for now. But given that you can type your password into it, it's mostly just an (unintuitive) aesthetic issue.
- also, <kbd>Esc</kbd> will "swipe up" (and down), so you don't have to actually use the mouse.
- there's always KDE (given gnome's usability trajectory, you might give this serious consideration)

Comment: `Esc` won't work for me. And just typing password on a multi-user machine doesn't work.

Comment: Not purely aesthetic, sometimes I can't get out of he screen - must ssh into laptop and kill X or force a reboot.

Comment: I've since switched to kubuntu (KDE), so I no longer have the issue, but possibly going to a virtual terminal (Ctrl+alt+f1, etc) and killing/disabling the screen lock might work (...is it `gnome-screensaver-command --lock` or `loginctl unlock-session` ? possibly must set DISPLAY? not sure, but worth a shot).

Comment: Due to bugs in the screen shield none of the above are guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 9):

Like estebarb previously stated, using `lightdm` fixes the issue for me on 18.04 LTS and 18.10. *However switching to KDE isn't necessary.* GDM just needs to be disabled/replaced with `lightdm`

Just open a terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get install lightdm
```

select `lightdm`, then press ok

[image: display manager selection screenshot]
You should be able to see your changes by  logging out. Then press Ctrl+Alt+F1 (*tty1*) and login there. then run:

```
sudo service gdm3 stop
```

then start lightdm with:

```
sudo service lightdm start
```

if it does jump right into lightdm you might have to press Ctrl+Alt+F7 to move back to *tty7*.

Comment: Seems like you also need to restart the machine for it to take effect.

Comment: @wjandrea right, I edited my answer to get there with a reboot.

Comment: Ah, I didn't even think of using a TTY. Though, on 18.04, the login screen runs on TTY1, and the desktop runs on TTY2.

Comment: oh so F7 is pointing to tty1, cool.

Comment: Thank you, this is the first solution that actually works for me. If automatic login was enabled, this disables that. You'll need to go to Settings/Details/Users and turn automatic login off then back to on.

Answer (score 8):

The "issue" is with GDM. After switching to KDE I changed to Lightdm, and I noted that in Gnome the lock screen was changed as well :D .

So, the solution is not using GDM, for example:

```bsh
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm # For previous Ubuntu default
```

Answer (score 5):

This was bugging me when setting up Ubuntu 18.04 VMs in Hyper-V under Windows 10.

I finally found

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 0
```

seems to disable the curtain, after disabling the screen lock through the GUI or a separate gsettings command.

Comment: Or in other words: Note that this also disables the automatic display switch-off, if that’s not suitable for your setup this approach is not for you.

Answer (score 1):

There is a recent gnome extension for this:

- [Remove Shield](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2245/remove-shield/)

This is compatible with 3.26 through 3.34 at the time of this writing.

Comment: I concur, this gnome-shell extension works perfectly on 19.04, no more swipe to unlock phone style hassle! Thanks!