# Gnome Energy Saving: How to turn of the watch screen?

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-gnome, lock-screen

I want to keep energy saving (12 minutes) but don't like the lock screen with the watch, whenever I come back. This two things unfortunately seem interlinked in Gnome.

[image: Settings]

How can I get rid of the watch screen / curtain?

Comment: So you just want the screen off after certain amount of time, but no locking, is that right ? Just disable GNOME  settings and use  `while true; do [ $(xprintidle) -ge 300000 ] && xset dpms force off ; sleep 1 ; done` The `xprintidle` is separate package so you'll need to install that with `apt` , and  outputs number in milliseconds, so that's 300 seconds there or 5 mins. Let me know if you want this as full and automated answer.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's locking, it's a needless full screen watch I have to click away by keyboard input. Where would that command go?

Comment: This command would be started through a `.desktop` file. The way autostart works on GNOME or any other GNOME-based desktop ( like Unity or Mate ) is by placing such file into `~/.config/autostart ` directory. The GUI tools like Startup Applications just do that behind the scenes, so there's no difference. As for that clock thing, disabling is done via methods described in https://askubuntu.com/q/970900/295286

Comment: @starkus: this option is already disabled.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Not sure if they are talking about the same problem, I want to get rid of the watch (not sure if it's a lock screen) and these options are for 17.10 as far as I see.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove "phone style" Gnome swipe to unlock](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967842/how-to-remove-phone-style-gnome-swipe-to-unlock)

Comment: @starkus : So far it does work on 18.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of people are annoyed by this "Screen Shield" or "Curtain" or "Swipe to Unlock" as it is can be called. This **Ask Ubuntu** question has 33 up-votes: [How to remove "phone style" Gnome swipe to unlock](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967842/how-to-remove-phone-style-gnome-swipe-to-unlock)

The answer with the most votes states:

> Open Ubuntu Software and install the GNOME Shell Extension called:
>
> Disable Screen Shield
>
> This works for Ubuntu 18.04
>
> Source: [Disable Screen Shield](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/672/disable-screen-shield/)

[image]

Note most users say it works with 18.04, but one commented it doesn't work. It could just be s/he didn't install it correctly.

Comment: Nobody says it works, but it seems to work at least on my machine, so I'm going to give you the award. On Github there are users who complain it won't work: https://github.com/lgpasquale/gnome-shell-extension-disable-screenshield/issues . It probably was not such a good move from Ubuntu to leave Unity behind.