# Disabling Lock Screen 18.04

Tags: 18.04, lock-screen

I've just installed Ubuntu 18.04 and I want to disable the lock screen.   I don't want to see it at all, neither on power-on nor after suspension.

I tried:

> Settings -> Privacy -> Screen Lock -> and changed 'Automatic Screen Lock' to 'Off'.

The lock screen still appears after suspension.
Any suggestions?

Comment: None of the answers seem to actually completely turn off that slider screen that appears when idle.

Comment: @tresf I got rid of the slider with the command from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1159085/507051) – if it helps you as well please upvote it so it rises!

Comment: In Xubuntu 18.04 you could switch locking on sleep in Power Manager dialog. In Xubuntu 19.10 also in Screensaver (Preferences) dialog.

Comment: still relevant in 20.04. major bug. so much facepalm.

Comment: Guys, I just tried what @Nadav said and... well it worked for me... left my pc unattended for quite a while. The screen did went black but after moving my mouse no lock screen... perhaps it's fixed now?

Answer (score 68):

## Disable Lock Screen

You can disable the lock screen permanently when waking from suspend.

First use this command to discover current settings:

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen
false
```

Now set it to `true` using this command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen 'true'
```

If you are unhappy with the new setting you can reverse it using:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen 'false'
```

---

## Disable Screen Saver Locking

There was some confusion where people think disabling the Lock screen also disables the screen saver which is invoked after a certain period of inactivity. The screen saver requires input to get your desktop back. Some people may want the screen saver to come on but not have it locked when waking up the screen.

To check screen saver lock status use:

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled
true
```

If true you can turn off screen saver locking with:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled false
```

To reverse the setting back use:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled true
```

---

In Gnome [screen locking guide](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-power-manager/stable/preferences-advanced.html.en_GB#advanced-preferences-locking) it says:

> ### 6.2. Screen Locking
>
> By default, GNOME Power Manager supports a simple locking scheme. This
> means that the screen will lock if set to **Lock screen** in
> gnome-screensaver when the lid is closed, or the system performs a
> suspend or hibernate action.
>
> There is a complex locking scheme available for power users that
> allows locking policy to change for the lid, suspend and hibernate
> actions. To enable this complex mode, you will have to disable the
> GConf key:
>
> - `/apps/gnome-power-manager/lock/use_screensaver_settings`
>
> Then the policy keys can be set to force a *gnome-screensaver* lock
> and unlock when the action is performed:
>
> - `/apps/gnome-power-manager/lock/blank_screen`
> - `/apps/gnome-power-manager/lock/suspend`
> - `/apps/gnome-power-manager/lock/hibernate`

Comment: Sounds very promising, but doesn't make any difference for me. I've changed the setting to `true` but the "privacy" screen still comes over the desktop after a period of time. Turning off locking in the system settings means I don't have to re-enter my password, but I still need to swipe the screen up to get back to where I was. Fresh Ubuntu Desktop 18.04.1 install.

Comment: @HeathRaftery There is another option to try as listed below: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled false`

Comment: @HeathRaftery On my system, you can hit escape instead of swiping up with the mouse.  Still annoying, but perhaps not as awful as the swipe gesture.  And +1 to the thought that this answer isn't a solution to the problem, unfortunately.

Comment: Well `lock-enabled` did the trick, but now I can't undo it!

Comment: after setting both `lockdown disable-lock-screen 'true'` and `screensaver lock-enabled false` I still get a big clock after wakening the screen on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS :-(

Comment: I found this answer after my screen lock mysteriously stopped working (no password required after waking from sleep, and `Super+L` suddenly did nothing). Settings > Privacy > Screen Lock showed all three screen lock controls as disabled. After running `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen false` the controls were working again and screen lock worked as expected.

Comment: What actually worked for me was using `dconf read /org/gnome/desktop/screensaver/lock-enabled` to get the value and `dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/screensaver/lock-enabled false` to disable the screen saver. Can use as-is with Ansible dconf module.

Answer (score 9):

Try this approach:

1. Launch terminal
2. Run `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled false`

This is a solution from [this FOSSLinux source](https://www.fosslinux.com/3893/how-to-disable-screen-locking-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts.htm/).

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver ubuntu-lock-on-suspend false
```