# Disable lock screen does not disable the slide up lock screen

Tags: desktop-environments, lock-screen, screensaver, 18.10

Using the instructions in this thread I disabled the lock screen:
[Disabling Lock Screen 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1048774/disabling-lock-screen-18-04)

...and the phone style slide-up lock screen is still enabled. It is not "locked". However, if I happen to be playing a game, that slide screen function completely locks up my computer. I can't get it back without a hard reboot. I would like a way to completely get rid of the phone style slide up requirement to return to my desktop. Just go from a blank screen (or screen saver) to the desktop when I move my mouse or press a key or anything to wake up the computer.

Comment: you never want to lock the screen? `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen true` try this command, when you want to enable make the value to false.

Comment: I wrote a couple of scripts with that command both to enable and disable the screen lock. Actual locking is not the problem. It doesn't lock, but that slide up screen is still there and locks up my computer if another "input intensive" program, like a game, is running when the slide up screen overruns my computer.

Comment: OK.. Slide up is the problem..Understood..you mentioned unity in tags..is this happening even when you use unity as DE?

Comment: ...ok, now I'm confused. I thought Unity came with the Gnome Desktop. If it doesn't then that tag should be removed. Apologies. And I do not understand "DE". (Been out of the tech circles for a couple of years since I didn't have a computer that could use modern os's) Do you mean Desktop Environment?

Comment: DE desktop environment.. By default the DE since 17.04 is "Ubuntu" there is "Ubuntu on Wayland" also. Couple of hrs ago I installed unity on my 18.10 by `sudo apt install unity` since it's a different DE there is no slide up environment. Any way this is off topic. Let's discuss about Ubuntu DE. Have you tried some other settings which prevents from locking the screen in power settings?

Comment: When I use that command in 18.10 default DE, my system works as if there is no screen lock function. So I didt see slide up anymore.

Comment: Yes, I've looked in every setting I could find. Power settings, privacy, everything I thought would change the desktop appearance or function. Not sure if I'm finding them all as they are not as obvious as earlier distributions.

Comment: Have you checked with `dconf-editor` tool also?

Comment: no, where in that tool would the settings for the slide up screen be located? (running now). (cannot go to chat as I'm too new, though that is where this discussion probably belongs.)

Comment: You should install it. `sudo apt update && sudo apt install dconf-editor` please note that there is no direct input for slider but many options which may avoid this slider.

Comment: Once you install dconf-editor search for keywords screen saver power ac battery lockdown lock suspend dim etc

Comment: The only solution seems to be to use something other than Gnome.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here's what I found as a solution, maybe not the best but it works.

```
sudo dconf_editor
```

I found these settings:

/org/ukui/power-manager/lock-use-screensaver set to [false]

Result: slideup lockscreen is gone.

/org/ukui/power-manager/lock-blank-screen set to [false]

Result: locking still enabled on blank screen

used the script:

```
# script to disable lock-screen
sudo gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen 'true'
```

Now lock screen is disabled. No slideup screensaver, I also have the script to re-enable the lock screen:

```
# script to enable lock-screen
sudo gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen 'false'
```

Comment: should be "sudo dconf-editor", dash not underscore.