# Preventing screen auto lock on lubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, using caffeine

Tags: lubuntu, lock-screen, caffeine

I have caffeine 2.9.8 and lubuntu 20.04.3. I want to prevent screen auto-lock while i'm reading a pdf.

In my typical usage i'm using Document Viewer (evince) in a normal window (not full screen) with caffeine activated through the indicator in system tray. But if i leave the system long enough without key press/ trackpad use, the screen keeps getting locked.

Am i using caffeine as intended? If not, is there something i can do to not have my screen getting locked?

I don't want to disable the screen lock completely.

Comment: [caffeine](https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/caffeine) is intended to "*prevent the desktop becoming idle in full-screen mode*" so won't have any impact on your usage. As I understand your issue, you need to tweak the [xscreensaver settings directly](https://manual.lubuntu.me/lts/3/3.2/3.2.20/screensaver.html) as per the Lubuntu manual.

Comment: @guiverc Thanks so much for your comment. I was apprehensive of this and wanted to confirm as i was unable to get any intended use instructions for caffeine. If yours is the only response after a few days of wait, I'll accept it as an answer (if you kindly post as such). This answers at least the major motivation behind my question.

Comment: Relevant question https://askubuntu.com/q/1115830/1075214

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[caffeine](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/caffeine) is intended to

> "prevent the desktop becoming idle in full-screen mode"

so won't have any impact on your usage.

As I understand your issue, you need to tweak the [xscreensaver settings directly](https://manual.lubuntu.me/lts/3/3.2/3.2.20/screensaver.html) as per the Lubuntu manual.