# How to exit screensaver with enter key

Tags: gnome, screensaver

I have to exit the screensaver by clicking with the mouse or trackpad and dragging up in order to get to the login screen. How can I exit the screensaver by hitting the enter key on the keyboard? (I used to be able to do it that way.) I am using 19.04.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to do it with <kbd>Enter</kbd> but it should work with you using  <kbd>Escape</kbd> assuming you have no password to unlock screen.

If you do have a password to unlock the screen than you can simply type it without using the mouse first to swipe the screen. As per:

- [How to remove "phone style" Gnome swipe to unlock](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967842/how-to-remove-phone-style-gnome-swipe-to-unlock)

Comment: Enter no longer works, escape doesn't work, in fact nothing on the keyboard works, and typing the password doesn't work either. I can only drag or swipe up to get to the login screen. I don't mind the clock screensaver, especially when I could just hit enter, then type my password. I don't really want to get rid of it, but having to click and swipe up with the mouse is getting annoying.